# Почему не работает код регистрации?

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

Начал учить PHP , делаю авторизацию и регистрацию , установил open server , зашёл в PhP my admin , создал базу данных с названием authorization_tutorial , далее создал таблицу users , написал код и ничего не работает , после регистрации данные не приходят на базу данных , что я сделал не так и как это исправить? Ниже весь мой код , в конце код подключения к базе данных , я думаю там и проблема , но на всякий даю весь код

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Формы авторизации и регистрации</title>
</head>
<body>
<!-- Форма авторизации -->
<form style="display: inline-grid;" action="authorization.php" method="post">
    Авторизация<br>
    Логин: <input name="login" type="text">
    Пароль: <input name="password" type="password">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
<!-- Форма регистрации -->
<form style="display: inline-grid; margin-left: 30px;" action="registration.php" method="post">
    Регистрация<br>
    Логин: <input name="login" type="text">
    Пароль: <input name="password" type="password">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

```
<?php
session_start();
if (isset($_SESSION['user'])) {
    echo("Вы вошли как " . $_SESSION['user']['nick']);
} else {
    echo("Вы не авторизированы.");
}
```

```
<?php
session_start();
include("db_connect.php");
$login = $_POST['login'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$md5_password = md5($password);
$query = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `login`='{$login}'");
if (mysqli_num_rows($query) == 0) {
    $_SESSION['user'] = ['nick' => $login];
    mysqli_query($db, "INSERT INTO `users` (`login`, `password`) VALUES ('{$login}', '{$md5_password}')");
    header("Location: /user.php");
} else {
    echo("Ошибка: Данный логин занят другим пользователем.");
}
```

```
<?php
session_start();
include("db_connect.php");
$login = $_POST['login'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$md5_password = md5($password);
$query = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `login`='{$login}' AND `password`='{$md5_password}'");
if (mysqli_num_rows($query) == 1) {
    $_SESSION['user'] = ['nick' => $login];
    header("Location: /user.php");
} else {
    echo("Ошибка: Данный логин или пароль неправильны.");
}
```

```
<?php
$connection = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','');
$sellect_db = mysqli_select_db('$connection','authorization_tutorial');
```

Comment: читай все ответы в дубликате...сверху вниз

Comment: ваш ответ бесполезен , там нет ответа почему данные не отправляются , у меня не вылетают ошибки , он пишет что данные отправлены , но данные не появляются в базе данных.

Comment: Насчет полезности не вам судить. Там и не может быть ответа, почему лично у вас данные не отправляются. Такой ответ может дать только астролог или ясновидящий. Но там написано, что надо сделать, чтобы узнать, почему данные не отправляются. В частности, как включить отображение ошибок.

Comment: Но в первую очередь надо выбросить в помойку тот учебник, по которому вы пишете этот код, и изучить вот этот: https://habr.com/ru/articles/662523/ . В частности, там есть ответ на вопрос, как сделать подключение к базе данных

Comment: @ЭлайджМакарони ещё раз: читай все ответы, начиная с "как включить отображение ошибок.".... Не надо быть ленивым или ребёночком маленьким, которого за ручечку проведут... Разработчик это тот, кто читает много информации, вникает, тщательно изучает и анализирует. В дубликате вся нужная информация для анализа есть... Если ты не готов читать и вникать и анализировать, тогда тебе стоит прямо сейчас всё удалить и рассмотреть другую сферу для деятельности